# Apache server restart error

Tags: apache, server

I am getting the following error while trying to restart apache

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA5Nw.png)

https://gyazo.com/830dad54ebe54d16600eefeb4e17650d

The error says something about an invalid command "Listed" not sure where that is.

Comment: Please use images just as an extra clarification. Instead copy-paste all the stacktrace into your question.

Comment: It is telling you the location of the error, exactly what file and what line in that file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message:

```
Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apach2/ports.conf;
Invalid command 'Listed' (...)
```

Comment: `Listed`, but yeah, it should probably be `Listen` :-)